# Cryptographic library for C/C++/Java/Python for Windows/Linux/Mac OS

Tags: open-source, cryptography

I'm looking for open source libraries for languages: C/C++/Java/Python for these 3 OSes: Windows/Linux/Mac OS.

I found `openssl` (for C/C++, linux), `Crypto++` (for C++, windows/linux/mac). But I need more, the more, the better.

If anyone knows a cryptographic library and can say, for which language and OS it is, I would be very thankful. I know I can just google for it, but I would like to know what lib would you people recommend, which has nice docs and api. :)

(I'm especially interested in Windows libs, because it's very hard to find any good library for it. But need those for Linux/Mac too;)

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NaCl](http://nacl.cr.yp.to/)(Networking and Cryptography library) is a good choice.
It provides a higher level abstraction of encryption and decryption.
If you are not familiar with cryptography, the High-level primitives are secure and easy to use.

Comment: And the more portable [libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) version which has [bindings](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium#bindings-for-other-languages) for python and java too.

Answer (score 3):

Java already comes with its own cryptography classes ([javax.crypto](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html)) and the Sun JCE provider.

The standard choice for C and C++ is typically [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/), which is multiplatform.

[PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) seems to be a good choice for Python.

Comment: And these are the choices of backend for the Highlevel [Google Keyczar crypto library](http://www.keyczar.org/) in java/c++/python

Answer (score 2):

The Java side of your question already has some answers [here on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430412/what-java-library-should-i-use-for-cryptography) that you might find useful.